got unwanted noise when im trying to put my voice live on my bot discord
I'm trying to put my voice live on my bot discord I succeeded but very inconclusive and I'm sure it only works with my microphone (what I do not want is for it to work with any microphone).
by “very inconclusive” I mean that my voice is audible but with a lot of unwanted noise
I tried to modify some variables like:
CHUNK, FORMAT, CHANNELS, RATE
and the most conclusive results were obtained with parameters:
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt32
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44800 

I'd also prefer to do it without ffmpeg (however, if ffmpeg is mandatory, it's no problem)
here is my code:

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import pyaudio

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt32
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44800

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

class MicrophoneAudioSource(discord.AudioSource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                             channels=CHANNELS,
                             rate=RATE,
                             input=True,
                             frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    def read(self):
        data = self.stream.read(CHUNK)
        return data

    def is_opus(self):
        return False

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.voice_states = True
intents.guilds = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.tree.sync()
    print(f'{bot.user}')

@bot.tree.command(name="join", description="Fait rejoindre le bot au canal vocal de l'utilisateur.")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def join(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.user.voice:
        channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
        voice_client = await channel.connect()
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Le bot a rejoint le canal vocal : {channel}', ephemeral=True)
        audio_source = MicrophoneAudioSource()
        voice_client.play(audio_source, after=lambda e: print(f'Erreur audio : {e}') if e else None)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Vous n'êtes pas connecté à un canal vocal.", ephemeral=True)

@bot.tree.command(name="leave", description="Fait quitter le bot du canal vocal.")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def leave(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.guild.voice_client:
        await interaction.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await interaction.response.send_message("Le bot a quitté le canal vocal.", ephemeral=True)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Le bot n'est pas connecté à un canal vocal.", ephemeral=True)


bot.run('TOKEN')

